# how to fix async await logic on nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to create a google bucket if it does not exist with the following logic:

```
async function createBucket(id){
    const bucket = storage.bucket("bucket-" + id);
    const exists = await bucket.exists();
    if (!exists) {
      console.log("creating bucket>>" + "bucket-" + id);
      try {
        await bucket.create();
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("error in creating bucket>>>", e);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("it already exists >>" + exists);
    }
}
```

strangely, I'm seeing `it already exists >> false`, when I should only see either `it already exists >> true` or `creating bucket>>bucket-123`. Any help with resolving this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: how `storage` is initialised? Why not use promise bucket.exits.then(...

Comment: This is likely subject to race conditions.

Comment: Is `storage.bucket("bucket-" + id);` an asynchronous call too? What happens if you write `await storage.bucket("bucket-" + id);`?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that `bucket.exists` returns an array with the result. In my case, `[false]`, which didn't seem to be suggested at here https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#exists .  The following fixes the issue:

```
async function createBucket(id){
    const bucket = storage.bucket("bucket-" + id);
    const [exists] = await bucket.exists();
    if (!exists) {
      console.log("creating bucket>>" + "bucket-" + id);
      try {
        await bucket.create();
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("error in creating bucket>>>", e);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("it already exists >>" + exists);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just tried in google cloud functions nodejs14 with 'latest' as include reference, got Invalid bucket name on exists()... still working for u?